# Image (VirtualBox/VmWare/Hyper-V) with Windows-10 & VS Dev Envoirnment

Tags: image, virtual-machine, vmware, hyper-v

Is there any Image available with Full Access (internet/usb port open) for VS Development Environment, with some 3rd Party tools like DevExpress or Telerik installed .. any help for home user for Free/ or minimum cost and goes beyond 30/90 days) as Student and home user

It would be more interesting if NCrunch or some likewise tools in it ..

Any other solution or component help is highly appreciated

Comment: I imagine there are a plethora of images available with USB/internet access available.. But what's preventing you from just installing the software you've listed yourself?

Comment: Trial License and Expires ..  I don't want to install any thing which will expire in 30 days !! and where are those Images available could you please refer me any link ?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn’t really the site for that so I don’t think I could provide you a link to images that give you free stuff. But what that being said, almost every piece of software you just mentioned was free with the exception of Telerik/DevExpress. We can’t necessarily provide you with free subscriptions to licensed software.